# How to make a config.exe file a companion file of its exe in wix installer

Tags: wix, windows-installer

What is the correct syntax for making a file companion to another? I googled a lot but couldn't find much besides theory.

My use case is that I updated .Net version in some services and now I am updating the installer too. Currently, this was the approach being used:

```
    <Component Id="cmp123" Guid="{guid1}">
              <File Id="fileid1" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.Dir1)\Service1.exe" />                
              <ServiceInstall Id="ServiceInstall1"
                              Type="ownProcess"
                              Name="SCService1"
                              DisplayName="SCService1"
                              Description="SCService1"
                              Start="auto"
                              Account="NT Authority\NetworkService"
                              ErrorControl="normal"
                              Vital="yes" >
                <util:ServiceConfig FirstFailureActionType="restart" SecondFailureActionType="restart" ThirdFailureActionType="none" ResetPeriodInDays="1" />
                <ServiceConfig DelayedAutoStart="yes" OnInstall="yes" OnReinstall="yes" />
              </ServiceInstall>
              <ServiceControl Id="ServiceControlService1" Name="SCService1" Start="install" Stop="uninstall" Remove="uninstall" Wait="no" />
            </Component>

            <Component Id="cmp456" Guid="{guid2}">
              <File Id="file2" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.Dir1)\Service1.exe.config" />
              <util:XmlFile Id="UpdateDotNetVersion"
                          File="[#file2]"
                          Action="setValue"
                          Name="sku"
                          Value=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2"
                          ElementPath="configurat/start/supportedRuntime" />                
            </Component>
```

I want to get rid of `util:XmlFile` and see if I could make this config file a companion file of the exe.

I tried the following cases:

```
<Component Id="cmp123" Guid="{guid1}">
                  <File Id="fileid1" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.Dir1)\Service1.exe" />                
                  <ServiceInstall Id="ServiceInstall1"
                                  Type="ownProcess"
                                  Name="SCService1"
                                  DisplayName="SCService1"
                                  Description="SCService1"
                                  Start="auto"
                                  Account="NT Authority\NetworkService"
                                  ErrorControl="normal"
                                  Vital="yes" >
                    <util:ServiceConfig FirstFailureActionType="restart" SecondFailureActionType="restart" ThirdFailureActionType="none" ResetPeriodInDays="1" />
                    <ServiceConfig DelayedAutoStart="yes" OnInstall="yes" OnReinstall="yes" />
                  </ServiceInstall>
                  <ServiceControl Id="ServiceControlService1" Name="SCService1" Start="install" Stop="uninstall" Remove="uninstall" Wait="no" />
                </Component>

                <Component Id="cmp456" Guid="{guid2}">
                  <File Id="file2" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.Dir1)\Service1.exe.config" />
                      <File CompanionFile="cmp123" /> 
                </Component>
```

Is this correct? Or do I have to add companion file to the .exe component and not in a separate component? Please help me with the syntax here.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the companion file like this:

```
<Component Id="cmp456" Guid="{guid2}">
    <File Id="file2" Source="$(var.Dir1)\Service1.exe.config" CompanionFile="fileid1" />                      
</Component>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I cannot make companion file to a file which is a keypath of its component. Setting keypath = no should help. Also, with this, when I upgrade to this build with the above changes, those services where I added companion files don't restart automatically. How should I make them restart?

Comment: Oh yeah CompanionFile can't be KeyPath since it uses the KeyPath from the companion file. I'll update the answer to remove KeyPath. Not about the Service not starting. Might be caused by the `ServiceConfig` I've never used that before.

Comment: When I was not using companion file, it worked fine. Instead of that, I was using util:xmlfile tag in config file and using setvalue action. I just wanted to avoid that else I have to add with every version upgrade. Let me know if you want the code for that, I can post it.